# Is it possible to use .join() to concatenate a list of strings in a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list, join, nested, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use `join()` in a nested list with an if statement. If the condition is met, I want to combine all indices from `[1:-3]`. Every time the `join()` function doesn't join the index.

**Input**

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b c d', 'e','f','g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

**What I have tried:**

```
a = [' '.join(str(inner_list)) for inner_list in a for i in inner_list if len(inner_list) >= 6 ]
```

I know the for loop is correct because the following code produces true for `a[1][0]` and iterates through `a[][]`. To my understanding, the loop is iterating over the correct part but won't `join()` from the index `[1][1]` to `[1][3]`. This is where I'm very confused.

the index

```
a = [print("true") for inner_list in a for i in inner_list if len(inner_list) >= 6 ]
```

Comment: What is expected exactly ? All strings from all nested lists concatenated ?

Comment: You should pass `list` instead of `str` to `join`.

Comment: don't name your variable `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slice the inner lists in the loop, but also pass the remaining inner lists as they are if they're smaller than 6 items. Here's an example:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

new_lst = [[l[0:1] + [' '.join(l[1:-3])] + l[-3:]] if len(l) >= 6 else l for l in lst]
print(new_lst)

# Output
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [['a', 'b c d', 'e', 'f', 'g']], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

`join()` takes a list as an argument instead of a string, and also try to refrain from using built in types like `list` as variable names.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This explains what I was doing wrong. Seems I didn't have an understanding of the way to `join()` works. I'll also change my variable name, so they are not types. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for inner_list in list_:
   for i in inner_list:
      if len(inner_list) >= 6:
         print("".join((inner_list)))
```

output:

```
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
```

i converted it to what it actually does , just i did not put it inside a list.
if you could specify the output you are looking for. Also
in your code you should remove str(inner_list) as i think it is not doing what you intend it to do.

please share intended output too , so i answer better.

your code updated

```
list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

list = [' '.join((inner_list)) for inner_list in list for i in inner_list if len(inner_list) >= 6 ]
```

output list :

```
['a b c d e f g',
 'a b c d e f g',
 'a b c d e f g',
 'a b c d e f g',
 'a b c d e f g',
 'a b c d e f g',
 'a b c d e f g']
```

Upon if you want to use that [1:-3] indexing too

```
list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

list = [' '.join((inner_list[1:-3])) for inner_list in list for i in inner_list if len(inner_list) >= 6 ]
```

output list :

```
['b c d',
 'b c d',
 'b c d',
 'b c d',
 'b c d',
 'b c d',
 'b c d']
```

ps : also try not to use default keywords as variable names like list

Comment: Hey, I've edited the question to the best of my ability to give a better explanation of what I'm trying to produce. I've taken your feedback on board. Thanks for the help.